# How do you use arguments with multiple words in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, arguments, discord.js

How do you get arguments with multiple words in discord.js?
As in
`!alert <content [multiple words]>`
because at the moment my code takes my command as
`!alert content1[0] content2[1] and so on`
So basically, how do you get it to make those arguments one string.

thanks

EDIT: This is my argument splitter:

```js
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arguments are most likely an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). You can use [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

---

```js
const args = ["content1", "content2"];

console.log("BEFORE JOIN \\/")
console.log(args)
console.log(args[0])
console.log(args[1])
console.log("BEFORE JOIN /\\")

console.log("AFTER JOIN \\/")
console.log(args.join(" "))
console.log("AFTER JOIN /\\")
```

Comment: It would work, but the idea is that you could create an **open ended** command which you don't know how many words there will be in. EDIT: Thanks, I think that actually works, I got confused with args[0] and args[1]. Sorry

Comment: Ok I tested it, but it's not working, as in [this image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/718813418714431621/769154151250657280/unknown.png) and [this image](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/718813418714431621/769154919479246858/unknown.png).

Comment: That's because `args.join(" ")` is not assigned to anything. `args` will remain unchanged. Try to log `console.log(args.join(" "))` to see the value directly. Or you can assign it to another variable and log it.

Comment: Ah ok so I could also add it to a variable?

Comment: Yes. For example: `const words = args.join(" ")`.